# ASP.NET Core with long background process and UI update

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, background-process

In my ASP.NET Core 2.x project, I want to run a long task and show the user the progress of this task. My project is hosted on Azure.

I don't know what is best practice to implement this function. I saw some posts around the web (such as [this one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/)) or [this](https://github.com/pgroene/ASPNETCoreScheduler/tree/master/ASPNETCoreScheduler) source code but none of them is updating the UI. Also, I read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx) by Dino Esposito written in 2012 but it is using ASP.NET MVC standard: maybe it is the way.

I'm not using React or SignalR but only jQuery.

I understand I can use `BackgroundService` that ASP.NET Core offers. I don't want to use tools like Hangfire.io because it is an expensive resource (it calls very often the database and in just one day I spent $30).

Comment: I am not sure about what your long running Task is, but would it be possible to _predict/guess_ the time needed for the task?

Comment: The task could take up to 5 minutes

Comment: What kind of progress do you want to display to the user then?

Comment: How long is the task expected to running for? I'd suggest using Azure Service Bus to send messages to an Azure Cloud Service instance which runs the task. You can then have the UI use a socket connection to the webserver to track the progress of this task running on the cloud service. As you can see, this is by no means a trivial task. As a point of note, you should avoid having a long-running operation running on your webserver, or you're just asking to have performance issues.

Comment: Yes, I have other services that use `Azure Service Bus` but there is not interaction with users. The reason of this task is to duplicate some records and trigger a validation. I want to display how the validation is going. If it is simple, think it as the typical progress bar when you book a flight.

Comment: In general, you're going to need to be able to update the client with the progress, which means you *need* SignalR. Your only option with jQuery only is to long-poll (basically hit a method every x amount of time to check on the status, until it's done). That's highly inefficient.

Comment: I understood `SignalR` was an obsolete project and it was replaced with something different. If `SignalR` is the way, I'll do that

Comment: For web project, it follows request-response, with `SignalR`, you could not update the client status from server. As the suggestion from Chris, comparing to jquery timer request to check the status, you may consider `SignalR`, and you could refer [Communicate the status of a background job with SignalR](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-status-background-job-signalr/)